# Counting Arcs to Places and Transitions in CPN-Tools

Tags: ml, petri-net

**Background**: **CPN-Tools** is a model checker using *colored Petri nets*, and it uses CPN ML as its query language. **CPN ML** is an extension of Standard ML, a type-inference functional language.

**Issue**: CPN-Tools is popularly used to model domains that require state space analysis. I am using it to model a domain where I need to know the number of incoming and outgoing arcs from a place. The difference is that I am looking at the Petri net model representation, not the state space. So when I say counting arcs from a place, I do mean a place, not a state space node. In my research so far, I have come across the `CPN'PlaceTable` and `CPN'TransitionTable` structures that contain properties of places and transitions, and look promising to my quest. However, I haven't found any CPN ML examples to help me figure out a way to count incoming/outgoing arcs using these structures.

**Question**: So my question, or actually questions are:

1. how do I use `CPN'PlaceTable` or any other method to count incoming arcs to a given place?
2. how do I use `CPN'TransitionTable` or any appropriate method to count outgoing arcs from a given transition?

**Case example**: I'm using this simple Petri net to give an idea about what I am expecting. Please view **[this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8qx3.png)** for the illustration.

In the image, we see 3 places and 2 transitions. What I want ideally is to be able to have CPN ML functions, `incoming(place_name)` and `outgoing(transition_name)` that work this way

```
incoming(Place1) = 0
incoming(Place2) = 2
incoming(Place3) = 1
outgoing(Transition1) = 2
outgoing(Transition2) = 1
```

**Other info**: I want to emphasize again that I'm not referring to state space nodes. There's lots of documentation in CPN-Tools about arc properties in state spaces, but I haven't found much information about my said question on the CPN-Tools support forums. And to make matters worse, `CPN'` structures in general are highly un-documented in CPN-Tools.